# Facing issue with BASE_DIR in Django

Tags: python, django

I am working with Django. Facing issue while using BASE_DIR because earlier this was like -

- BASE_DIR =
  os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(**file**)))

and now after the update -

```
 - BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
```

Can someone help as I am using static files in my project as below -

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static',
STAICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR, 'ecom/static',
]
```

earlier than this I was using BASES_DIR as -

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STAICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'ecom/static'),
]
```